# NServiceBus - How do I call NSB via web service but asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, web-services, nservicebus

I want to achieve something similar to the webservice bridge sample but i don't want to wait for a response from the webservice. I want the call to be asynchronous.
What is the best way to do this?

Should I just use the webservice bridge and call ProcessAsync as opposed to Process?
or Should I not use the webservice bridge and just create a webmethod that calls Global.Bus.Send?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expose your NServiceBus endpoint using the built-in WebService functionality, then you'd do this like you call any web service asynchronously. The webservice bridge sample shows how you can set up your own web service rather than using the built-in functionality.

Comment: Thats great. I didn't realize I could do that. Thanks.